# Get rid of tiny gap between vector tiles

Tags: geojson, openlayers-3

In my testcase http://drifted.in/other/ol/tiles.html there is a tiny gap between tiles even though the GeoJSON coordinates are same.

```
7/68/84 - xMax: 1565430.3392804079 (meters)
7/68/85 - xMin: 1565430.3392804079
```

Is there any rounding involved? Or is my border X coord calculated incorrectly, hence rendered slightly shifted?

Comment: Your page has a lot of `404` json files. From `40.json` to `170.json`. Maybe this is the reason.

Comment: @JonatasWalker those are non existing tiles outside my area (the extent is not set because of [buggy behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699032/tile-grid-extent-settings-causes-creating-lot-of-useless-requests) in the current version).